# Rewrite JSON value by javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

For example i have some JSON data

```
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {
    "total": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "title": null,
        "content": "Kyle Th...",
        "sourceDomain": "Facebook",
      },
      ]
```

and i'd like to change the sourceDomain from facebook to youtube by javascript and ajax, how may i do it?

i have done something like below to try to achieve my goal

```
$("#button").click(function(){

                 $.ajax({
                  url: "/api-path" ,//getting the api
                  type: 'get',
                  success: function(data){ 
                    data.region = "Hong Kong";
                  }
            });
         });
```

and i like to change the sourceDomain from facebook to youtube, how can i do it?

**After i go thought the answer below, am i able to do something like**

```
$("#button").click(function(){

                 $.ajax({
                  url: "/api-path" ,//getting the api
                  type: 'post',
                  success: function(data){ 
                    jsonObj.result.data[0].sourceDomain  = 'youtube';
                  }
            });
         });
```

UPDATE 2

I have tested my method in this way and i tried to output something in the console for better understanding

```
 $.ajax({
                      url: '/buzz/view/data/editRegion?profileId=' + profileId + "&region=" + "1%2B2%2B3%2B4%2B99" ,//getting the api
                      type: 'get',
                      success: function(data){ 

                        var result = data.result;
                        console.log(result);

                    }   
                });
```

[image]

Comment: How JSON structure is related with `ajax` ?

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

First your JSON string is not valid. It has an incorrect syntax:

Lets correct It:

```
{
    "message": "Success",
    "result": {
        "total": 1,
        "data": [{
            "title": null,
            "content": "Kyle Th...",
            "sourceDomain": "Facebook"
        }]
    }
}
```

The next, you have to convert JSON string to JavaScript object:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse('{ "message": "Success", "result": { "total": 1, "data": [{ "title": null, "content": "Kyle Th...", "sourceDomain": "Facebook" }] } }');
```

Now your `jsonObj` is a JavaScript object. You can access to Its properties:

```
jsonObj.result.data[0].sourceDomain  = 'http://www.youtube.com';
```

**Update:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/buzz/view/data/editRegion?profileId=' + profileId + "&region=" + "1%2B2%2B3%2B4%2B99", //getting the api
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {

        var result = data.result;
        console.log(result);

        result.data[0].sourceDomain = 'YOUR_URL';
    }
});
```

Comment: No need to parse json data using JSON.parse. You can just assign json data variable to javascript variable. and you can access its properties.

Comment: i have update my question can you pleas take a look?

Comment: `var result = data.result; console.log(result); result.data[0].sourceDomain = 'YOUR_URL';`

Comment: Do i need to do the .parse still?

Comment: Your `data` variable already JavaScript object. You can use It without `JSON.parse()`. Your jQuery's ajax script converts json string to JavaScript object in the background.

Comment: And why am i using type:get here since i want to rewrite the value, shouldn't we use $.post in order to send things to back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this..

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api-path", //getting the api
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            data.result.data[0].sourceDomain = 'youtube';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the value of "data" that you are getting in the success handler?

Comment: Can you try "data.result.data[0][0].sourceDomain = 'youtube';" inside success handler